# Save a Dictionary as JSON in SQL with Dapper

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, dapper

I need to save a Dictionary into my table with Dapper.  I have gleaned from other posts that I need to use the SqlMapper stuff now available in Dapper.

In my example here I have a property called ExtendedProperties which I wish to serialize to JSON and place in the ExtendedProperties column of my table.  Here is the code I am using to attempt this.  Note that this code works for hydrating on the way out, but fails on an insert with the error:

> No mapping exists from object type
>   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to
>   a known managed provider native type.'.

```
public class ExtendableObject
{
    public ExtendableObject()
    {
        ExtendedProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> ExtendedProperties { get; set; }

    private string ExtendedPropertiesJson
    {
        get
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ExtendedProperties);
        }
        set
        {
            ExtendedProperties = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(value);
        }
    }
}

public class ExtendableObjectTypeMap : SqlMapper.ITypeMap
{
    private readonly SqlMapper.ITypeMap _original;

    public ExtendableObjectTypeMap(SqlMapper.ITypeMap original)
    {
        _original = original;
    }

    public ConstructorInfo FindConstructor(string[] names, Type[] types)
    {
        return _original.FindConstructor(names, types);
    }

    public SqlMapper.IMemberMap GetConstructorParameter(System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructor, string columnName)
    {
        return _original.GetConstructorParameter(constructor, columnName);
    }

    public SqlMapper.IMemberMap GetMember(string columnName)
    {
        if (columnName == "ExtendedProperties")
        {
            return new ExtendedPropertiesMemberMap();
        }
        else
        {
            return _original.GetMember(columnName);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A mapper that finds a private member to do the serialization and hydration
    /// </summary>
    public class ExtendedPropertiesMemberMap : SqlMapper.IMemberMap
    {
        public string ColumnName
        {
            get { return "ExtendedProperties"; }
        }

        public FieldInfo Field
        {
            get { return typeof(ExtendableObject).GetMember("ExtendedPropertiesJson", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Single() as FieldInfo; }
        }

        public Type MemberType
        {
            get { return typeof(string); }
        }

        public ParameterInfo Parameter
        {
            get 
            { 
                return null; 
            }
        }

        public PropertyInfo Property
        {
            get { return typeof(ExtendableObject).GetMember("ExtendedPropertiesJson", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Single() as PropertyInfo; }
        }
    }

SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(typeof(ExtendableObject), new ExtendableObjectTypeMap(SqlMapper.GetTypeMap(typeof(ExtendableObject))));
```

Comment: Can I clarify: is your intention to store json as a string? Or for it to map the key/value pairs to parameters? Or?

Comment: I am storing the entire Dictionary<string,object> as a string into an nvarchar(max) column, in JSON.  This is legacy code I am converting from NHibernate which uses a custom type to currently do this.

Comment: As a really quick dirty solution, I sometimes use another property to store the string value of the table column value which the database writes / reads from. This property converts the list/dictionary in the get method to a string, and in the set updates the list/dictionary whenever the string value is set.

Comment: I had the same exception.  Debugging revealed I actually was passing a dynamic.